# C++ bool with ofstream

Tags: c++, boolean, ofstream

I have been programming c++ for around half a year. And im trying to write to another file with a bool. I cant figure out how to just output what I have written to the txt file. Sorry for my english it isnt my mother tongue. Heres my code:

```
int main(){
system("cls");
std::cout << "1. Add ingredient" << std::endl;
std::cout << "2. Delete ingredient" << std::endl;
std::cout << "3. Show you ingrediens" << std::endl;
std::cout << "4. Show recipies" << std::endl;
std::cout << "5. Exit" << std::endl;

int choice;
std::cin >> choice;

switch (choice)
{
case 1:
    add();
    break;
case 2:
    deleteIngredient();
    break;
case 3:
    showIngredient();
    break;
case 4:
    showRecipies();
}
}

void add(){
system("cls");
const int maxIngredients = 10; // max ingredients
std::string ingredients[maxIngredients]{  /*kjøtt*/  "beef", "chicken", "pork", "lamb", "rabbit",
    /*fisk*/  "salmon", "tuna"}; // ingredients
bool hasingredient[maxIngredients] {}; //bool for ingredients
bool exit = false; // exit request
std::cout << "Welcome, type your ingredients " << std::endl;
while (!exit){
    std::string yourIngredients;
    std::cin >> yourIngredients;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < maxIngredients; i++)
        if (yourIngredients == ingredients[i]){
            yourIngredients[i] = true; // <================ set flag of indegrient
            if (yourIngredients[i] = true){
                std::cout << "You have choosen " << ingredients[i] << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    std::string txtname = "YourIngredients.txt";
    std::ofstream ingredientsList(txtname);
    ingredientsList << "Your ingredients are: " << std::endl;
        int y = 0;
        for (y = 0; y < maxIngredients; y++){
            if (hasingredient[y] = true){
                ingredientsList << ingredients[y] << std::endl;
            }
        }

        ingredientsList.close();
    if (i == maxIngredients){
        if (yourIngredients == "Exit" || yourIngredients == "exit")
        {
            exit = true;
        }
    }
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your english correctly, you want to print what you have wrote to file, don't you?

Add this:

```
std::cout << ingredients[y] << std::endl;
```

after this:

```
ingredientsList << ingredients[y] << std::endl;
```

I have noticed that you have of if case:

```
if (hasingredient[y] = true){
```

It's not comparison, it's assignment.

Comment: As you see you can write 10 different ingredients, when you for example write 1 then beef and then exit. I want to add that to the YourIngrediens.txt file.